# Mapping between database entities and domain objects or DTO

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, architecture

I have a complex mapping logic between my database objects and domain objects. Hence, I am not using any third-party library like AutoMapper. I am wondering what would be a better code design:

Option #1. Having a mapper abstracted as IServiceNameMapper and inject as a dependency into IServiceName

Option #2. Write extension methods to database objects and domain objects to convert between them.

I am leaning towards option #1 as I get a nice separation of concern, wherein the mapping logic is abstracted away from the core service logic and injected as a dependency into service. This also gives me ability to extend or change the mapping logic in the future without having to change the service implementation.

Any thoughts?

Comment: For the record, having complex mapping logic isn't a reason *not* to use AutoMapper. There's no mapping logic that AutoMapper can't handle, given all of its extension points. You can point AutoMapper to custom converters/resolvers for the really exotic stuff and still utilize some of it's conventions.

Comment: This link may give some idea - htmlhttps://ramesh-java-design-patterns.blogspot.in/2018/03/converter-pattern.html

Answer (score -1):

From purely architectural point of view option 1 is better. However sometimes this can be overdesign. For example I have no interest in separating my DTOs from the Entities so what I do is just accept the entity in the constructor of the DTO or create ToEntity() method on the DTO and keep the mapping in the DTO. Theoretically it is bad because the DTOs cannot be used in another project without pulling in the entities but in practice I have estimated that the risk that I will need that is pretty low since Silverlight is now dead :) Unless you are into extreme unit testing I think the extension methods are fine. Basically the only problem that can occur is that your unit tests will test both the method and the mapping logic and you won't be able to write a test that only tests the method. Big deal!